# How to refactor rust assert_json_snapshot_matches into assert_json_snapshot

Tags: unit-testing, rust, rust-cargo

I upgraded my rust `insta` package to the latest 1.8.0, on the process found `assert_json_snapshot_matches` has been replaced with `assert_json_snapshot`. I tried to run the test just by replacing the method. But it's doesn't work.

```
let actual = &create_oci_json(&site, "whoami").expect("json should be okay");

assert_json_snapshot_matches!("oci_json", &actual, {
        ".process.user.uid" => 42,
        ".process.user.gid" => 42,
});
```

After changing the method name to `assert_json_snapshot` it throws this error.

```
let actual = &create_oci_json(&site, "whoami").expect("json should be okay");
let expect = json!({
        ".process.user.uid" : "42",
        ".process.user.gid" : "42"
});

assert_json_snapshot!(vec![actual, &expect]);
```

Edit:

```
Missed errors:
        501 │+]
────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
To update snapshots run `cargo insta review`
thread 'container::contained_v2::tests::test_create_oci_json' panicked at 'snapshot assertion for 'oci_json' failed in line 413', /Users/mohamednizar/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/insta-1.8.0/src/runtime.rs:1048:9
```

Since I was new to the cargo, I forget to run the `cargo insta review`. After the run of this command, the issue was resolved.

Comment: What command is giving the error? I don't see the error message in your question; was it mistakenly left out?

Comment: @BrianBowman , 
Since I was new to the cargo, I forget to run the `cargo insta review`. After the run this command, the issue was resolved.